# Please let me know why image.fromarray in PIL is not running as plt.imshow in matplotlib

Tags: image, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I tried to display picture by a using image.fromarray from an array but icouldn’t get the right picture as I get from plt.imshow. Do you have any idea about it ?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

row,col,ch=img_array.shape
mean=0.0
sigma=20
gauss = np.array(np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col,ch)),dtype=np.int64)
noisy = img_array + gauss
new_image = Image.fromarray(noisy,'RGB')
new_image
```

[image: not requested image]

if i run it by plt.imshow, the requested pic is below

```
 plt.imshow(noisy, interpolation='nearest')
 plt.show()
```

[image: requested image]

Comment: Because the type is `int64` which doesn't fit very well into a PNG file that can only handle 8/16-bit samples.

Comment: @Mark Setchell thanks for the response i tried int8 /int16 but stil it is not as i expected , do you have any other idea ?

Comment: I can't run your code because I don't know what `img_array` is.

Comment: 256X256 lena RGB image

Comment: Please ensure your code is **Minimal, Complete and Verifiable** - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You will be much more likely to get assistance if you make it easy for people to run your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your types are too big - `int64`.

Change the lines from:

```
gauss = ...
```

to:

```
gauss = np.array(np.random.normal(mean,sigma,(row,col,ch)),dtype=np.int8)                  
noisy = (img_array + gauss).astype(np.uint8)                                               
Image.fromarray(noisy,'RGB').save('result.png')
```

[image]

Ideally you would normalise too, because you are adding a pixel in the range 0..255 to some noise in the range -20..+20 which means you will overflow 255 at some points.